# I want to delete a string from each line in a file

Tags: shell

I have a file whose contents are

```
/a/b/c
/a/b/d/xyz
/a/b/c/nmxnxlcs
...
```

I want to delete the string `/a/b/` from the file.
I want to do it using shell script.

Comment: `sed` should work well for that.

Comment: From your example, does the string only occur at the beginning of the line? What if the line was "/a/b/c/a/b/foo"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not mentioned in the problem statement, the example suggests that you only want to delete the string if it's at the beginning of the line:

```
sed 's:^/a/b/::' myfile.txt
```

This will change:

```
/a/b/c/foo.txt
```

To:

```
c/foo.txt
```

And will change:

```
/a/b/c/x/a/b/foo.txt
```

To:

```
c/x/a/b/foo.txt
```

And not to:

```
c/xfoo.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's#/a/b/##' file
```

if you want to update the file,

```
sed -i.bak 's#/a/b/##' file
```

it will create a backup `file.bak` and update `file` with the new values.

As [mbratch comments in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19379890/1983854), it can happen that you just want to replace lines *starting* with `/a/b/`. In that case, you can use:

```
sed 's#^/a/b/##' file
```

where `^` stands for beginning of line.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
/a/b/c
/a/b/d/xyz
/a/b/c/nmxnxlcs
hello/a/b/aa
$ sed 's#/a/b/##' a
c
d/xyz
c/nmxnxlcs
helloaa
```